# How to find out if nfc tag is locked without overwriting anything on it already?

Tags: c#, nfc

I know I could just try to read/write over what is already there, but that would erase anything already there. Is there any specific apdu or similar thing that could show it?

Comment: There a number of Nfc Tag types that are locked in different ways depending on what data they are storing and there are also another load different ways of password protecting Tags which effective locks them as well, so without exact details of the Tag make and model it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Okay so there's no easy way to do it for every key, that's what I was wondering. I'm making an app that's going to sort many different kinds of tags from over the years in storage, so it should work for atleast most commercial tags. NTAG 21x family, mifare ultralight, 1k, 4k, etc. All of them are made by nxp. This isn't commercial software or anything too serious, so maybe I should just try to read and write.
edit: The reader I'm using is acs122U if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your list of Tags you are probably going to handle each type of Tag separately.

For example even on the NTAG 21x family of cards which are just different sizes of the same card you could lock it by the following methods.

1. Static Lock bytes, which you would read bytes 2 and 3 of Page `02h`, this works for all sizes.
2. Dynamic Lock bytes, which you would need to read `28h` or `82h` or `E2h` depending on the size of the card.
3. Read the `AUTH0` config page at `29h` or `83h` or `E3h` to see if they have been locked by password, again dependant on the card size.
4. Read the Capability Container on byte 3 of page `3h` as the [Ndef data standard for a Type 2 card](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf) as this indicates if writing is "locked", though I have Type 2 compatible cards (not fully compliant) ignore this at the hardware level and allow writing even when write access should be prevented by this.

Then all the Mifare Classic series of cards will have a different set of locking mechanism that are again stored all over the Tags.

And some of these methods can partially "lock" a Tag in that they can just restrict portions of a Tag but not the whole Tag.

So possible but a lot of work, to check all the configuration places it is possible to "lock" a Tag.

Comment: Thanks I marked this as solved. So in short if I wanted to do it properly i'd have to do all of the above + more. I was searching for an easy method as this software isn't that serious business. My current method is to read a byte, try to write something over it and check if it changed.

Comment: Unfortunately the easiest method is the one you are using, of try to write and check for error/value not changing.